# Possible to change JRE versions via command line?

Tags: java, jre

We are running into an issue where we must have two concurrent JRE versions installed for a program that doesn't provide backward compatibility.

Is it possible to disable/enable a JRE version via the command line?

You can access the option in the Java control panel applet (javacpl.exe) on the Java tab, by clicking the View button, followed by checking off "Enabled."

Answer (score 0):

You can always give the complete path to use a specific installation. For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8\bin\java" -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
```

Comment: This might up be useful in some contexts.  I am using IE, so this will not work.